# Launch an OS X app at login

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa

I have done and check all steps in this tutorial few times: https://theswiftdev.com/2015/09/17/first-os-x-tutorial-how-to-launch-an-os-x-app-at-login/

Demo app is working fine. But my app isn't :( The launcher app didn't start after login.

`SMLoginItemSetEnabled("samy.LauncherApplication" as CFString, true)`

This key is exactly in login items. I checked it with program:
[image]

I tried to move Main app in Application folder. Don't work too

But my `LauncherApplication` won't launch. Help with some suggestions, where do I can find issue.

Comment: Re-check all steps carefully. If you forget/misspell one little piece the functionality breaks silently.

Comment: nothing happens:( I tried re create it. Looks like in tutorial is something missing...

Comment: [This tutorial](https://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/) definitely works – I'm basically using it in a few Swift projects – however it's in ObjC

Comment: @vadian oh, I create new project it works:( But with organization project-  doesn't (

Answer (score 1):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50417312/implemented-helper-app-but-does-not-launch-on-login/50735880#50735880) is actually a bit of a duplicate, but it is newer and outlines your issue with a bit more detail.

As per the answers in that question, your issue could be that:

1. The system cannot find the correct version of your application to launch. In this case you should test your application on a clean system (perhaps using a VM).
2. You could have accidentally made a mistake following the instructions in the tutorial, such as deleting the storyboard file in the launcher application. In this case, you may just want to be sure that you follow each step correctly. When I used that tutorial, following all the steps precisely worked for me, as suggested in the comments here by @vadian.

Also note that the tutorial you followed has been updated for Swift 4 here: https://theswiftdev.com/2017/10/27/how-to-launch-a-macos-app-at-login/

Answer (score 0):

I followed all the instructions on these various articles perfectly as well and couldn't get it to launch either.

Luckily, someone solved this problem for us as an open source Swift Package - [LaunchAtLogin](https://github.com/sindresorhus/LaunchAtLogin). Easy integration and solved my problem starting up.