# Implemented helper app but does not launch on login

Tags: swift, macos

I have a need to boot my Mac application when the user logins in.

This is what I did:

I created a new Coca Application Target.

• Build Settings set "Skip Install" to "YES"

• Info.plist "Application is background only" to "YES"

• Enabled Sandbox on both main and helper app.

• Added Copy File Phase to main application: Wrapper, Contents/Library/LoginItems, added Helper.app

**AppDelegate.swift of Helper application**

```
import Cocoa
import ServiceManagement
extension Notification.Name {
    static let killLauncher = Notification.Name("killLauncher")
}

@NSApplicationMain
class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {

    @objc func terminate() {
        NSApp.terminate(nil)
    }

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        print("hi")
        let mainAppIdentifier = "co.myprogress.osx"
        let runningApps = NSWorkspace.shared.runningApplications
        let isRunning = !runningApps.filter { $0.bundleIdentifier == mainAppIdentifier }.isEmpty

        if !isRunning {
            DistributedNotificationCenter.default().addObserver(self,
                                                                selector: #selector(self.terminate),
                                                                name: .killLauncher,
                                                                object: mainAppIdentifier)

            let path = Bundle.main.bundlePath as NSString
            var components = path.pathComponents
            components.removeLast()
            components.removeLast()
            components.removeLast()
            components.append("MacOS")
            components.append("TODOs Menubar") //main app name

            let newPath = NSString.path(withComponents: components)

            NSWorkspace.shared.launchApplication(newPath)
        }
        else {
            self.terminate()
        }
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        // Insert code here to tear down your application
    }


}
```

**AppDelegate.swift of Main Application**

```
func applicationDidFinishLaunching(_ aNotification: Notification) {
        let launcherAppId = "co.myprogress.TodosMenubarHelper"
        let runningApps = NSWorkspace.shared().runningApplications
        let isRunning = !runningApps.filter { $0.bundleIdentifier == launcherAppId }.isEmpty

        let ret = SMLoginItemSetEnabled(launcherAppId as CFString, true)
        print(ret)

        if isRunning {
            DistributedNotificationCenter.default().post(name: .killLauncher,
                                                         object: Bundle.main.bundleIdentifier!)
        }

    }
```

**Testing**

• Cmd + B to build application

• Right click .app in Product > Show in Finder

• Launched application

• Log out

• Log back in -- Expected: Application boots. What Happened: Application Did not boot

Comment: I couldn't get the process to work myself even following the various blog articles perfectly, luckily I found [this github repo](https://github.com/sindresorhus/LaunchAtLogin) that solves it in a graceful way. Followed his instructions for integrating it and it worked first try.

Answer (score 4):

Not a full solution, but perhaps it helps on debugging:

I followed [this tutorial](https://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/) which describes steps very similar to yours. I also archived and exported the application as a Developer ID application and installed it into /Applications.

Result: it didn't work for me either.

After opening `Console.app` the `system.log` showed many lines like the following, appearing every 10 seconds:

> May 24 21:18:16 FooBar com.apple.xpc.launchd[1] (my.domain.TestHelper[43372]): Could not resolve CFBundleIdentifier specified by service: -10814: my.domain.TestHelper

I.e. registering the helper via `SMLoginItemSetEnabled` works, but the system cannot find it. After opening the main app manually and disabling the launch-on-login feature, no more messages showed up. Deregistering also seems to work.

At last I tried to open the main app manually in Terminal.app:

> $ open -b my.domain.Test

It opened many old builds from various Xcode build locations and archives! Hence rather try the feature with a **clean system**. Otherwise the launch services my open unexpected versions of the main or helper apps. Testing the feature from Xcode seems to be impossible.

[Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Security/Conceptual/AppSandboxDesignGuide/AppSandboxInDepth/AppSandboxInDepth.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011183-CH3-SW29) also documents some conditions that must be met for login items to work.

With a clean system I could get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

Looks like you followed [Tibor Bodecs' tutorial](https://theswiftdev.com/2017/10/27/how-to-launch-a-macos-app-at-login/).

I went down the same path, and mine didn't work but the Github project associated with the tutorial did work.

Perhaps you made the same mistake as me. In the Launcher Application, I thought the instructions were to delete the storyboard file instead of the main window within the storyboard. After redoing this part, and keeping the storyboard file, my application launched on login.

As a follow-on to @mshmidt's answer, it looks like the existing builds problem is one faced by a lot of other developers. Looks like you can use [lsregister to help clean out your system](https://www.electrollama.net/blog/2017/4/7/login-items-in-macos-1011-and-newer). I preferred using a virtual machine to test things out since you can snapshot it and easily roll back.

One last note is that I actually prefer the Tibor Bodecs tutorial over the [Tim Schroeder](https://blog.timschroeder.net/2012/07/03/the-launch-at-login-sandbox-project/) one because it seems simpler, has more recent xcode screenshots, and has the Swift code examples.

Comment: I know it's been years but there are no good documents about this and maybe just like me, there are some devs who are building apps that target lower than macOS 13. Don't delete the main storyboard file, delete scenes inside (or maybe leave some empty scenes). I tried everything and it wasn't working until I deleted my launcher app and recreated it but this time didn't delete the main storyboard. Hopefully, this will help someone...

Answer (score 0):

**IMPORTANT:** Thanks to mschmidt's answer I've stumbled upon system.log entries like these:

> Could not resolve CFBundleIdentifier specified by service: -10814: noorganization.iGlanceLauncher
>
> (noorganization.iGlanceLauncher): Service only ran for 0 seconds. Pushing respawn out by 10 seconds.

as well. Note the **second** entry. Since I've had the same issue with my launcher not being launched on startup, I read some of the [Apple Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPSystemStartup/Chapters/CreatingLaunchdJobs.html) about daemons and agents containing this:

> Important: If your daemon shuts down too quickly after being launched, launchd may think it has crashed. Daemons that continue this behavior may be suspended and not launched again when future requests arrive. To avoid this behavior, do not shut down for at least 10 seconds after launch.

So I just

1. Added `sleep(15)` into my launcher before it would finish
2. Built the project
3. Put the main application into the application folder of a clean mac os machine

and it worked, even though the same application would **not autostart** on the **clean mac machine** without the 15 sec delay before termination. Unfortunately the autostart still doesn't work on my main machine. I think my bundle identifier of the launcher got blacklisted from launchd or so, but I believe if you do it correctly as just explained on your main machine, it will also work on that. Hope I can help somebody with that